# Using more than one keyword for index search with Hibernate Search

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

My application, that uses **Hibernate Search 4.5.0.Final**, is working fine when I try to search with just one keyword. But if I try to use two keywords, the second keyword is not used by Hibernate Search, just the first one is considered by HS.

For example, if I try to search "James", the search works fine and the application returns all "James" that I have in the index. But if I try to search "James Hetfield", the results are, again, all "James" and not the unique result with name "James Hetfield". I need to treat "James Hetfield" as **"James *AND* Hetfield"**.

**EDIT:** I've made a mistake. The search works with two keywords, **but with "OR" and not "AND"**.

**My code:**

```
public List<Person> search(String keywords) throws DAOException {
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
        Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("name", "email", "username", "phone").matching(keywords).createQuery();
        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(query);
        fullTextQuery.setProjection("name", "email", "username", "phone");
        Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("name_order", SortField.STRING));
        fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
        return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error searching index: " + keywords, e);
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What analyzer are you using? Could you try calling `ignoreAnalyzer()` before `matching()`?

Comment: Another option might be to split the string and issue a query per word using a `BooleanJunction` and calling `junction.must(subquery)`.

Comment: I think I am not using any analyzer because I am not specifing any analyzer. Maybe I am using the default (if have one). I tried to call `.ignoreAnalyzer()` and now it didn't find anything, even with one keyword.

Comment: I edited my question. The search works with two keywords, but it's using "OR" and not "AND".

Comment: Thanks @thomas. I've made some changes, but I followed your tip about `BooleanJunction`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution. I've split the String and used BooleanQuery. Thanks to [@thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas). Here is my code:

Splitting:

```
String[] arrKeywords = keywords.split(" ");
this.search(Arrays.asList(arrKeywords));
```

And then, searching:

```
public List<Person> search(String keywordsList) throws DAOException {
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();

        List<Query> queryList = new LinkedList<Query>();
        Query query = null;

        for (String keyword : keywordsList) {
            query = qb.keyword().onFields("name", "email", "username", "phone").matching(keyword).createQuery();
            queryList.add(query);
        }

        BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        for (Query q : queryList) {
            finalQuery.add(q, Occur.MUST);
        }

        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(query);
        fullTextQuery.setProjection("name", "email", "username", "phone");
        Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("name_order", SortField.STRING));
        fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
        return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error searching index: " + keywords, e);
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the key word MUST during query building.  Hibernate Search also supports combining queries using various strategies:

-SHOULD: the query should contain the matching elements of the subquery

-MUST: the query must contain the matching elements of the subquery

-MUST NOT: the query must not contain the matching elements of the subquery

The aggregations are similar to the boolean ones AND, OR and NOT.

```
    Query combinedQuery = queryBuilder
   .bool()

   .must(queryBuilder.phrase()
   .onField("productName).sentence("samsung galaxy s8")
   .createQuery())

   .must(queryBuilder.keyword()
   .onField("productCategory").matching("smartphone")
   .createQuery())

   .createQuery();


    // wrap Lucene query in an Hibernate Query object
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(combinedQuery, Product.class);

    // execute search and return results (sorted by relevance as default)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Product> results = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

This reference is obtained from the link http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search